# Identify a specific HTML Table cell

Tags: html

I want to identify a specific cell within a HTML Table created using php with data imported from Google Sheets. If a (date) cell is empty I want to delete the contents of the cell that is immediately below that one. I have tried using Boolean tags, HTML DOM but have not been successful yet.

```
<? var data = getData(); 
var btrue = []; ?>
for (var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
    <tr>
    <? for (var j = 4; j < ((data[i].length-4)/2) + 4; j++) {     
        <? if (data[i][j] instanceof Date) { 
            var d = new Date(data[i][j]); 
            var n = d.toDateString(); 
            data[i][j] = n; 
        }
        if ((data[i][j] == 'OPEN') && (data[i][j] == 'CLOSED')) { 
            if (data[i][j] == "") {
                btrue.push(false);    <!-- set to false if no date -->         
            } else {
                btrue.push(true)            
            }; ?>  
            <?= data[i][j] 
        } else if ((j <= 21) && (btrue[8] != true) ) { ?>
            <?= data[i][j] ?>
            <select id ="newSched" onchange="getOpenSched(this)" >     
                <option value="$">--Select 2 Change--</option>
                <option value="val1">OPEN</option>
                <option value="val2">CLOSED</option>
            </select>               
        <? } ?>            
        </center></td>        
    <? } ?>
    </tr>
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call given javascript function to remove cell that is just below the empty cell

```
function removecellbelow() {
var table=document.getElementById("mytab1");

var rowcount=table.rows.length;
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) { 
for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) { 
if(col.innerHTML==''){
//check if it's not last row of table 
if(i<rowcount - 1)
table.rows[i+1].cells[j].innerHTML='';
}
}

} 

   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had to add window.onload = function to load the Table - why is that necessary? Also I need to delete 2 empty rows imported from google sheets - I used the delete/hide blank rows/cols Add on but they are still there - any suggestions?

Comment: The solution I provided will work after your table loaded, and if you want to delete empty row(all empty td) then you can add a flag variable to check if all columns(td) are blank, if so, keep index of that row in an array and after loop completed, remove those rows

Comment: After you have indexes to delete, you can use given code to delete row     document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(<index>);

Comment: Thank you again - I understand how the function works - but it doesn't appear to recognize an empty cell - when is a cell empty?- using alert (col.innerHTML) - an empty cell appears with HTML tags as <center> (empty space) </center> - which looks correct but it doesn't do the check and so no changes are made to the cell below!

Comment: you can change if condition as 
if(col.childNodes[0].innerHTML.trim()==''){

Comment: Use it only if you are sure that all <td> will have <center> tag in it, 

trim() will save you even if extra white spaces will be there